# Webdriver switching to wrong iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have gathered a certain amount of iframes by using find_elements_by_xpath

```
frames = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(self.PATH_TO_FRAMES)
```

When I go through them, I see that I indeed have gathered the correct URLs:

```
for frame in frames:
    print(frame.get_attribute("src"))
```

Result:

```
CORRECT URL 1
CORRECT URL 2
CORRECT URL 3
CORRECT URL 4
CORRECT URL 5
```

However, as I go through them like this, the result is not the correct one:

```
for frame in frames:
    self.driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
    print(self.driver.current_url)
    self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Result:

```
CORRECT URL 3
CORRECT URL 4
CORRECT URL 5
URL FROM IFRAME AFTER THAT BUT THAT WAS NOT IN THE LIST 1
URL FROM IFRAME AFTER THAT BUT THAT WAS NOT IN THE LIST 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you must provide waiting time  while switching frame

Comment: @Piyush I have checked, all frames have loaded by the time I explore them and switch through them. But I tested with both a wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) and an implicitWait and got the same results.

Comment: if possible can you give me url

Comment: There may be a chance of nested frames. suppose, if frame 1 is inside of frame 3, then first you switch to frame 3 first, then only you can switch to frame 1.